# Effective sentence formation

Tags: phrase-usage

> X had invited person Y on Saturday to have a discussion on a topic on
> Sunday (the discussion will happen on Sunday).

Is the above sentence correct? How can this be written effectively?

Comment: It could be more effective**ly** written (or more clearly expressed) by putting 'On Saturday' at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

> On Saturday, X invited Y to come ***the next day*** and discuss a certain
> topic.